# xml and as3 data into an array and buttons to navigate

Tags: xml, arrays, actionscript-3

I have an xml file that holds data and i have my fla file calling the data. I have 3 buttons (attractions, pubs and restaurants), i have the attractions button calling only the attractions data items. I've created dynamic text fields (name_Text.text = myXML.attractions.place.name[0];)for the data to be called in flash but Id like to have the data placed into an array when the data is retrieved so the user can navigate between each node when clicking the next/back buttons.  Your help will greatly be appreciated in this matter.

also, i can't seem to get the images to show, i can import only the name of the image, why is this happening?

```
function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void 
{ 
   myXML = XML(myLoader.data);

   var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument();
    // Ignore spacing around nodes
    xmlDoc.ignoreWhite = true;
    //initialize menuXML
    var menuXML:XML = XML(myLoader.data);
    // Parse the XML data into a readable format
    xmlDoc.parseXML(menuXML.toXMLString());
    //initialize i
    var count:Number = 0;
// Run the "for each" loop to iterate through all of the menu items listed in the external XML file
for each (var attractions:XML in myXML..attractions.place) {

   name_Text.text = myXML.attractions.place.name[0];
   info_Text.text = myXML.attractions.place.info[0];
   thumbnail_Text.text = myXML.attractions.place.thumbnail[0];
   thumbnail_Title_Text.text = myXML.attractions.place.thumbTitle[0];
   image_Text.text = myXML.attractions.place.image[0];
   address_Text.text = myXML.attractions.place.address[0];
   web_Text.text = myXML.attractions.place.web[0];

   count++;
   trace(count);
   }

}
```

Comment: For your question regarding inserting your data into an Array, please consult ASDocs - Working with arrays / Indexed arrays - Inserting array elements (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee0.html)

For your question regarding loading images, please consult ASDocs - Loading SWFs and Images (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c83.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d96)

Comment: Can you post the xml you're using?

Comment: here is a simplified version. i have 3 main items in my xml list, attractions, pubs, restaurants. each heading has 5 childnodes, they all have the same format as the structure below.

Comment: <myXMLList>
 <attractions> 
  <place>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>Blackpool Tower</name>
   <info>518ft.</info>
   <thumbnail thumbnailWidth="55" thumbnailHeight="70">thumbs/tower.jpg</thumbnail>
   <thumbTitle>this is the first image</thumbTitle>
   <image>images/tower.jpg</image>
   <address>The Promenade  Blackpool,  FY1 4BJ</address>
   <web>http://www.theblackpooltower.com/</web>
  </place>
 </attractions>
</myXMLList>

Comment: As for the storing data in array, I suggest to create class corresponding to the structure of item in the xml or you can keep xml as it is navigate through it. As for the loading images, could you post related part of the code?

Comment: function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void 
{ 
   myXML = XML(myLoader.data);
   
   var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument();
 // Ignore spacing around nodes
    xmlDoc.ignoreWhite = true;
 //initialize menuXML
 var menuXML:XML = XML(myLoader.data);
 // Parse the XML data into a readable format
    xmlDoc.parseXML(menuXML.toXMLString());
 //initialize i
 var count:Number = 0;

Comment: // Run the "for each" loop to iterate through all of the menu items listed in the external XML file
for each (var attractions:XML in myXML..attractions.place) {

  name_Text.text = myXML.attractions.place.name[0];
   info_Text.text = myXML.attractions.place.info[0];
   thumbnail_Text.text = myXML.attractions.place.thumbnail[0];
   thumbnail_Title_Text.text = myXML.attractions.place.thumbTitle[0];
   image_Text.text = myXML.attractions.place.image[0];
   address_Text.text = myXML.attractions.place.address[0];
   web_Text.text = myXML.attractions.place.web[0];

Comment: i put my full as3 code online so you can see my project code at http://kennycox.comeze.com/thisIsMyAS3.as Thank you

Comment: my xml code :)  http://kennycox.comeze.com/myXMLList2.xml